# Issue double selector CSS input:not(:placeholder-shown)::before

Tags: css

I'm trying to use two selector CSS but he doesn't work..

```css
input:not(:placeholder-shown)::before {
            content: '';
            display: block;
            height: 80px;
            width: 80px;
            background-color: red;
        }
```

```html
<span id="input_1_1_3_container" class="name_first">
    <input type="text" name="input_1.3" id="input_1_1_3" value="" aria-required="true" placeholder="Prénom">
                                                    
    <label for="input_1_1_3">Prénom*</label>
</span>
```

I dont' understand why when i write in the input ce before not appear.

Anyone have and idea why she does not work ? I search a long time ...

Comment: share your html code as well

Comment: @TikkaMasala Please use `input:placeholder-shown {content: ''; display: block; height: 80px;width: 80px;background-color: red;}`